# Накопление (сохранение истории) данных из одной таблицы в другую

Tags: sql, postgresql

Имею 2 таблицы например:
tab_temp

```
id (PK) | value1 | value2 | value3
1       | 1      |  2     |  3
2       | 4      |  5     |  6
3       | 7      |  8     |  9
```

tab_all

```
id (PK) | value1 | value2 | value3
0       | -1      |  -2     |  -3
```

таблицы имеют одинаковые типы столбцов и одинаковые названия столбцов

можно ли так обеспечит накопление данных в таблице tab_all?

```
INSERT INTO tab_all 
    SELECT *
    FROM 
        tab_temp
    EXCEPT SELECT *
    FROM
        tab_all
```

чтобы в итоге получилось в таблице tab_all следующее содержание:
tab_all

```
id (PK) | value1  | value2 | value3
0       | -1      |  -2    |  -3
1       | 1       |  2     |  3
2       | 4       |  5     |  6
3       | 7       |  8     |  9
```

и есть ли недостатки / уязвимости при таком подходе?

Comment: `*` означает подставить колонки в том порядке, в котором они определены в базе. Если в таблице `tab_temp` удалить `value2` и опять создать, то они поменяются местами и значения начнут идти в в неправильные колонки. Если хочется надёжно, надо генерировать SQL на лету по схеме и исполнять через `EXECUTE dynamic_sql_script`.  Ну и колом, конечно, очень быстро это всё встанет, если размер `tab_all` будет расти.

Comment: А как решить данную задачу? При этом сохранить максимальную скорость работы?

Comment: Про задачу ты ничего не написал. Ты написал только про копирование из таблицы в таблицу, что может быть решением какой-то задачи, а может и не быть

Comment: если у тебя дупликаты исключаются по primary_key, то посмотри в сторону `INSERT INTO tabl_all (...) select ... from tab_temp ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-insert.html